# Complex cron with chalice.Cron

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, chalice

I have an AWS Lambda scheduled with chalice cron, in Python. Up until now, it's been

```
@app.schedule(chalice.Cron("0/30", "5-11", "*", "*", "?", "*"))
def foo(event):
```

And that works fine; it runs overnight (don't ask why). However, I want to set it up a second version to run on weekends:

```
@app.schedule(chalice.Cron("0/30", "1-4,12-15", "*", "*", "0,6", "*"))
def bar(event):
```

I tested this in [a crontab checker](https://crontab.guru/#0/30_1-4,12-15_*_*_0,6), and it says that `0/30` is nonstandard and the final `"*"` (for year) is wrong, but the rest should work in any cron engine. However, I get `Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid` anyway. Chalice docs ([(1)](https://aws.github.io/chalice/topics/events.html#scheduled-events),[(2)](https://aws.github.io/chalice/api)) are silent on what cron expressions are supported. Is this a feature Chalice Cron lacks, or should I look elsewhere for the source of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range was not the issue; the nonstandard day-of-week/day-of-month syntax was. The fix was

```
@app.schedule(chalice.Cron("0/30", "1-4,12-15", "*", "?", "0,6", "*"))
def bar(event):
```

Which makes AWS trigger the event on days 0 and 6 (Sun, Sat) regardless of which day of the month they fall on. Additionally, [CloudWatch docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions) cover this information better than Chalice-specific docs.